# Radeon slow GPU rendering

Tags: rendering, gpu

It's my first post on the Blender Stack Exchange..

As I'm not a professional Blender user I think the following PC setup is sufficient for my hobby:
AMD Ryzen 9 3900X, Radeon VII, Linux Kernel: 5.3.0-53-generic x86_64, Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia, v2.83.0 latest releas 2.

In order to get GPU available in Blender I installed the driver "amdgpu-pro-20.10-1048554-ubuntu-18.04"

Not rendering anything fancy but just the standard initial cube - result is really disapointing.

Having seen some interesting tips here, which I have applied but saw no improvement.

Any one a good idea how to get the situation improved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, share a screenshot.

Comment: Have you enabled OpenCL in the preferences and selected GPU rendering in the render tab?

Comment: Yes, OpenCL is set as well as render engine device to GPL.